# Create a custom Task.WhenAll() in java?

Tags: java, c#, multithreading

I've been trying to port bits of a project of mine from C# to Java (more accurately, from .NET Core 3 to Android 5.0), one of these bits relies heavily on the TPL (lots of async/await, spawining many tasks, etc...), and I couldn't get the performance I wanted usaing a simple `ConccurrentQueue<T>` and a bunch of threads polling from it.

So I embarked on the foolish journey of building my own small TPL for java, and I think I succeeded in the fundamentals (Task lifecycle, global and thread-local Task queues, building a Task that can 'await', etc...), however I am stuck at replicating C#'s `Task.WhenAll()` efficitiently.

Right now, I implemented it with a normal task that simply returns **IDLE** until all of the other tasks it can wait for are over, however this task sits in the task queue for potentially very long periods of time, consuming an entire Thread that could otherwise `Wait()` without draining the device battery.

I had an idea of creating* an ad-hoc thread that would specifically wait for all the waiting tasks completed signal, thus avoiding putting the waiting task in any queue.

However this 'solution' has the potential problem that there could be easily tens or hundreds of threads waiting, if my `Task.WhenAll()` is used frequently (which it is).

I have been looking through the .NET documentation on the TPL looking for some implementation details (tho no source code for .NET Core/5, as this project will not be MIT-compatible), with little luck.

If anyone can help in any way, I'd be super grateful!

Also, if I've missed a library/utility comparable to .NET's TPL in Android 5, feel free to let me know.

*: of course, such threads would be saved and re-used if necessary, with the usual timeouts when there's no work for them.

Comment: hmm, java has own "task" implementation ...  `Callable` + `ExecutorService`  +  `Future` ... I would love to see how you implement `await` without compiler generated state machine

Comment: What kind of project it was so you converting it from .net core to android, I believe it wasn't mobile?

Comment: To @Selvin, in  a very verbose fashion: https://gist.github.com/jstefanelli/5fc432431511486394d5b9bfbbe7de0f

Comment: To @AlexeyRumyantsev, it's an OpenGL rendering-engine thingy, and I found my performance bottleneck to be iterating through a scene graph with a moderate number of nodes. I'm not sure bad parallelism is the culrpit of my poor performance, but I want to try this and rule it out completely

Comment: Since ExecutorService has already been mentioned, I'll note that an `ExecutorService`'s [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) allows you to submit a collection of `Callable<T>` and will cause that thread to block until all tasks are completed.  It's not exactly like Task.WhenAll, but it's somewhat close.